# Do WSL use the python installation which is installed on Windows host?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i have some python installations in my windows machine. Recently, i need Linux environment for studying. I have the question that "Do i need to install Python again in WSL environment ? or Not ( since WSL use the same python installations of Windows host)". Please give me answers, Thank you in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), you are not using the same Python installation as your Windows host by default. WSL runs its own separate distribution of Linux, and you will need to install Python in that environment if you want to use it.

You can install Python within your WSL distribution by using the package manager for your specific distribution. For example, on Ubuntu you can use the apt package manager to install Python by running the command `sudo apt install python3`.

In summary, if you want to use Python in your WSL environment, you will need to install it within the WSL environment itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, they use the Python from the Linux distro. You can determine that by running `ls -l $(which python)` or `ls -l $(which python3)` inside the WSL or just by running Python inside WSL with no Python installed on the Windows machine. If the answer returned would have been a link to the "External" windows machine you would have seen it. But you are going to see something like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.7M Nov 20 17:14 /usr/bin/python3.10
```